# Can I assign a value, of an item in an array of objects, from another value from an array of objects without referencing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays of objects

```
A = [{x: x1, y: y1 ...}, {x: x1, y: y1}];
```

and I am iterating over these upading

```
B.forEach((d, i) => d['x'] = A[i]['x']));
```

However, whenever I am now updating `B, A` is updating as well.

Edit: Apparently the problem is not above, so here is all I do:

I have 3 arrays of objects, `A, B, C`.
I initialize them as follows:

```
    A = await d3.json(endpointA).then(res => res);
    C = await d3.json(endpointB).then(res => res);
    B = [...A];
```

They are the bound with `.data(B)` to some svg elements with `d3` and updated.

I am guessing they get referenced but while I have now a few months behind me, this is still my first javascript project so I am not 100% sure.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Post more code; the problem is not with what you posted, but with how you populate the arrays in the first place.

Comment: @Pointy I added how I start the arrays, depending on a variable `B['x']` is either updated with `A['x']` or C['x']`. `B` is bound to some svg elements.

Comment: Well the initialization code looks like it initializes A and C to the promise objects returned from the `.then()` calls, and that doesn't make a lot of sense. However understand that initializing B that way will fill B with references to the same objects that are in A.  Those objects will not be cloned.  If you want to do that, you'll have to write code that creates clones according to your needs.

Comment: @Pointy apologies, the initializations have an `await` before, doesn't this mean it initializes to the value? I edited it., Sorry if this is still dumb question.

Comment: Right, that's what I assumed, or you wouldn't have been in the situation described in the question. Cloning objects is difficult in relation to the complexity of the objects. If you're getting "pure data" structures from d3, that might not be too hard, and in fact the trick of using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` may work fine.

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `B` only clones array itself, but you also need to clone the objects inside the array:

```
B = [...A].map(o => Object.assign({}, o));
```

As @Pointy pointed out, this will only work if objects don't have nested objects.

For nested objects you'd need a deep cloning function:

```
B = cloneObj(A);

function cloneObj(obj)
{
  const ret = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
  for(let o in obj)
  {
    if (obj[o] && typeof obj[o] == "object")
      ret[o] = cloneObj(obj[o]);
    else
      ret[o] = obj[o];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: This will work, but if the constituent objects in the source array have sub-objects, the OP may have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thank you and thanks @Pointy the first one worked, I don't have nested objects in the objects, its just an array of objects. Thanks a million~!!

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is this:

```
B = [ ... A ];
```

That makes a *shallow copy* of A. Making deep copies of objects is, in the general case, pretty difficult because objects can have lots of "shapes". In your case, however, it's likely that the following trick will work:

```
B = A.map(v => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)));
```

That uses the JSON facility to stringify each object in A, and then parse it back to an object.  That trick **does not always work**; in particular, if an object has functions or various other data values that cannot be serialized to JSON, it will strip those values out of the objects.

Comment: I want to emphasize that the JSON technique only works in limited situations, and I'm not 100% sure that it will work for the real data involved here.